# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on my nextjs app when hosted on Cloudways

Tags: node.js, next.js

One of the pages of my app is showing

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

but on local its working fine. I have hosted my site on cloudways. I tried everything but not able to figure out where is the problem.

the site url: `fortunedeed.com/web-admin`

I was getting the same error in one of the other pages, then I changed the `index.js` file name in that folder and it started working. One index file is also there in `web-admin` folder, I changed the filename and it worked but with a fetch error.

But this should not be the case as I cant change the filename of all the `index.js` files.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a server configuration issue (and therefore, off-topic):

1. http://fortunedeed.com/web-admin redirects to https://fortunedeed.com/web-admin (`http://` changed to `https://`)
2. https://fortunedeed.com/web-admin redirects to http://fortunedeed.com/web-admin/ (added backslash at the end and back to `http://` again)
3. http://fortunedeed.com/web-admin/ redirects to https://fortunedeed.com/web-admin/ (`http://` changed to `https://` again)
4. https://fortunedeed.com/web-admin/ redirects to `/web-admin` (because it can't find a file that serves as "index"), so back to #2